# Не виден новый реквизит в админке Django у пользователя

Tags: django

Создал новый проект из шаблона Cookiecutter Django. В нем уже есть кастомизированная модель пользователя.

Добавил новый реквизит:

```
    from homes.models import Homes

    class User(AbstractUser):
      name = CharField(_("Name of User"), blank=True, max_length=255)
      homes = models.ForeignKey(Homes, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

В admin.py добавил:

```
    list_display = ["username", "name", "is_superuser", "homes"]
```

Полный код:

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(auth_admin.UserAdmin):

form = UserChangeForm
add_form = UserCreationForm
fieldsets = (("User", {"fields": ("name",)}),) + auth_admin.UserAdmin.fieldsets
list_display = ["username", "name", "is_superuser"]
search_fields = ["name"]
```

В списке объектов это поле есть, а при редактировании из админке его нет. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно в admin.py список полей ограничен переменной [fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields).

В данном случае нужно добавить имя нового поля в этот перечень либо удалить, чтобы в режиме редактирования/модификации объекта выводились все поля.

Пример:

```
class FlatPageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('url', 'title', 'content', 'homes')
```

Comment: Добавляю ваш пример - ругается, что должен быть tuple или список. Меняю на fields = ['url', 'title', 'content', 'homes'] , ругается что <class 'sun.users.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E005) Both 'fieldsets' and 'fields' are specified.

Comment: @Леонид пробовали перевести последнее сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 0):

В `fieldset` в UserAdmin нужно добавить новое поле. Например:

```
fieldsets = (("User", {"fields": ("name", "homes",)}),) + auth_admin.UserAdmin.fieldsets
```